# Как передать нескольким view один экземпляр viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Работаю с паттерном MVVM. Есть два представления которые работают с одним viewmodel. Для каждого представления создается свой экземпляр viewmodel, но мне нужно чтобы представления использовали один экземпляр, как мне это сделать?

Comment: Можешь рассказать для чего это вообще нужно? Типа чтобы обе вьюшки работали с одинаковыми данными из вьюмодели? Можешь приложить скриншоты вьюшек?

Comment: @Pekor Одна вьюшка отображает список, через другую добавляю объект в список. Из-за того, что у каждой вьюшки свой экземпляр вьюмодели, при добавлении объекта он не появляется в списке. Сейчас сам подумал, создал статик класс, где хранится нужный объект вьюмодели, а затем задаю контекст через данный статик класс. Но мне кажется такая реализация немного топорной.

Comment: хм, не проще ли для хранения использовать файл или базу данных?

Comment: @Pekor Так вьюмодель к БД обращается.

Comment: View это окно или что? Как именно сейчас создаете вьюмодель? Покажите код. Есть паттерн ViewModelLocator - он может помочь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте для VM некий аналог синглтона, т.е. создайте статический метод(например с именем GetInstance), который будет всегда возвращать единый экземпляр класса(VM). А дальше создаете хоть сколько угодно окон по следующему типу:

```
MyWindow win = new MyWindow
{
   DataContext = MyViewModel.GetInstance()
};
```